# Indentation in Jade

Tags: pug

I'm trying to understand how *indentation* in Jade works.

```
div(class="p")
    div(class="c")
        p x
      p y
    p z
```

renders as

```
<div class="p">
  <div class="c">
    <p>x</p>
  </div>
  <p>y</p>
  <p>z</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain why Jade renders `x` and `y` at different levels but `y` and `z` at the same level?

**Edit**

Changed the `li` tags to `p` tags. The question wasn't about putting out the correct HTML. I'm trying to understand how Jade works under the hood. Even if only single-level indentation is valid, I don't get an *error* or *warning* from Jade for using multi-level indentation.

It's because of this that I wanted to know how Jade interprets / processes multi-level indentation, and so I took the above as a toy example to understand that.

Another similar example could be :

```
div(id="1")
       div(id="2")
     div(id="3")
   div(id="4")
```

is rendered as

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="2"></div>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <div id="4"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, `<div id="3"></div>` isn't rendered as a child of `<div id="2"></div>` but `<div id="4"></div>` is rendered as a child of `<div id="3"></div>`.

Comment: It's not valid to go down more than one indentation level.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

In general, according to Jade, you must only go **one** level deeper (not outer) of indentation at a time, if we 're talking about nested elements (or divs, if you better function with HTML).

That is, after the definition of `x` in your example, what Jade expected was either to go a level inside, or continue on the same level. Instead, you got it one level before, which is not valid.

*Also, on a side note, you should include the `li` elements into a list element (i.e. `ul`, `ol`), so the correct format should be like:*

```
div(class="p")
  div(class="c")
    ul
      li x
      li y
      li z
```

For further reference, please consider reading the [official docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/) or even better, for your case, this [nesting](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#nesting) example.

**Edit**

The above stand for general purposes, too, but what should be also taken into account, is that the compiler saw your nested indentation being abandoned after `div(id="2")`. That is correct, as what you specified is that the `div(id="3")` is one level outer.

What I mean, is that the compiler understood that you 're done with the nesting of the second element. So, it thought that you just mismatched the alignment in your editor and instead placing `div(id="3")` in the same vertical level as `div(id="1")`, you placed it somewhere inner, but still, before `div(id="2")`, which indicates that you 're done with the nesting of `div(id="1")`, according to what I mentioned before editing the post ("one level deeper").

Subsequently, placing `div(id="3")` in the same level with `div(id="1")`, makes him apply the general (and the easiest one for us to understand) rule of indentation ( `div(id="4")` in a nested element of `div(id="3")`, as `div(id="3")` is outer than `div(id="4")`  ).

So, it is something like a step-by-step compilation.

To sum up, here are the compiler steps and structuring of the html markup:

- `div(id="2")` is a nested element of `div(id="1")` -> ok, create a nested html tag for the first element, simple as that:

  `<div id="1">
   <div id="2"></div>
  </div>`
- `div(id="3")` hmmm it's not on the same level with `div(id="2")`. Is it more inside? No. It is more out? Yes, so it might be a parent element, just like `div(id="1")`, so I'll place in the same level with `div(id="1")`

The updated html is:

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="2"></div>
</div>
<div id="3">
</div>
```

- Ok, let's go to `<div id="4">`. What is this about? Its indentation is still the same shit with `div(id="3")` (oh my God, they don't follow my rules), but I've just considered `div(id="3")` to be a parent (on the same level with `div(id="1")` ) element, so, because this one is more inside that my consideration for `div(id="3")`, which is a parent element, I will just consider `div(id="4")` as a nested element for `div(id="3")`.

So, it updates the  to be like

```
<div id="3">
  <div id="4"></div>
</div>
```

which for the whole document, means an update like the following:

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="2"></div>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <div id="4"></div>
</div>
```

*What first needs to be understood is that the gaps we have in mind are not handled the same way from Jade's compiler perspective (i.e. editor tabs not always produce nested elements the way they are thought to do from the human mind, on a first touch of Jade).*